# Python 3 list comprehension optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a list comprehension in python 3 for list of list serially numbers according to given range. My code works fine with  but problem is with big range it slows down and take a lot of time. I there any way to do it other way? I don't want to use numpy.

```
global xy 
xy = 0
a = 3
def func(x):
    global xy 
    xy += 1
    return xy 

my_list = [[func(x) for x in range(a)] for x in range(a)]
xy = 0
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Why using `global xy` on first line? It is only useful **inside** any functions or classes.

Comment: This code is pretty weird. `func` does nothing but increment and return a global counter, you could just use `range` instead. What are you actually trying to achieve? This looks like an XY problem to me. In addition, you don't seem to fully understand what the `global` keyword does, which might confuse things further.

Comment: `for  x in range(a)` will produce 0..3 and your desired list most likely would be: `[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]]` since there are `for x in range(a)` on top of another.

Comment: i think he want to build a enough big list.in this way to tell us `problem is with big range it slows down and take a lot of time`

Comment: You are already declaring xy in global namespace, it's redundant to use `global`. You could use a generator and print each list at a time, this would save memory, but I'm not sure if it would speed up the process. To speed it up, you'd need to spawn multiple processes and build the lists in parallel (assuming you have multi-core processor available).

Comment: my mistake, it's shifted by 1, he wants `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

Comment: @RenatoByrro I am from pure c and did not practice coding a long and now trying to lean python3 by my own. I have downloaded some tutorial but most of them seems weird. I am reading the documentation and trying learn so this is why my code looks weird. Thanks for your  suggestion but if you can give me references it will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In exactly the form you asked

```
[list(range(x, x + a)) for x in range(1, a**2 + 1, a)]
```

**Optimizations**

If you're only iterating over inner list elements

```
(range(x, x + a) for x in range(1, a**2 + 1, a))
```

If you're only indexing inner elements (for indices `inner` and `outer`)

```
range(1, a**2 + 1)[inner * a + outer]
```

And if you're doing both

```
[range(x, x + a) for x in range(1, a**2 + 1, a)]
```

Note: I think you can eek a little more performance out of these by combining them with mousetail's answer

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
t = [list(range(a*i + 1, a*(i+1) + 1)) for i in range(a)]
```

It seems pretty fast for a>100 even, though not fast enough for inside a graphical loop or event handler

Comment: Nice, roughly 5-10x faster than the original.  And less code.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do what you have done. You can have a clearer picture once we do a  performance check

```
import timeit

# Process 1

setup = '''
global xy
xy =0
a=30
def func(x):
    global xy
    xy+=1
    return xy
'''

code = '''
my_list = []
for x in range(a):
    my_list1 = []
    for x in range(a):
        my_list1.append(func(x))
    my_list.append(my_list1)
'''

print(min(timeit.Timer(code, setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))

# Process 2

setup_2 = """
global xy
xy =0
a=30
def func(x):
    global xy
    xy+=1
    return xy

"""
print(min(timeit.Timer('[[func(x)for x in range(a)] for x in range(a)]', setup=setup_2).repeat(7, 1000)))

# Process 3

setup_3 = 'a=30'
print(min(timeit.Timer('[[(x*a)+b for b in range(a)] for x in range(a)]', setup=setup_3).repeat(7, 1000)))

# process   4
setup_4 = 'a=30'
print(min(timeit.Timer('[list(range(a*i + 1, a*(i+1) + 1)) for i in range(a)]',  setup=setup_4).repeat(7, 1000)))
```

OUTPUT

```
0.21270840199999996
0.1699727179999999
0.08638116599999979
0.028964930000000333
```

You can see that the last process is fastest because all the operation is in local variable rather than global variable. Almost the speed is 10x faster.

```
[list(range(a*i + 1, a*(i+1) + 1)) for i in range(a)]
```

> Use local variable if possible:
>
> Python is faster retrieving a local
>   variable than retrieving a global variable. That is, avoid the
>   “global” keyword.